# Wrong results with Search API

Tags: github, github-api

I'd like to retrieve the number of closed issues in a repository.

With `GET /search/issues?q=repo:tidyverse/dplyr+type:issue+state:closed` I obtain:

```
total_count 3322
incomplete_results  false
```

However [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues) I can read that there are 3334 closed issue at the moment:

[image: number of issues on dplyr]

Why is there a difference of 12?

Comment: that's strange even open is giving 130 record count. If you look here issue 3825 is closed, but it still get displayed in state:open search, try contacting github support https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:tidyverse/dplyr+type:issue+state:open&page=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted GitHub support and they triggered a manual reindexing of the issues in this repository, so the search results are now consistent.

However they said that it can happen again:

> Unfortunately this isn't a trivial issue, and although our engineering team are continuing to investigate this - we don't have a timeline on this being 100% resolved, 100% of the time.